# How can I delete the zip file based on actual file created date and time in Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have 3 folders which are 12 days older, and are zipped on current day. How can I delete the file based on the created date of the file instead of the zipped date of the file? For eg. 01/05/2021 dir1 02/05/2021 dir2 03/05/2021 dir3

When I zipped it today, it is like this , 14/05/2021 dir1.zip 14/05/2021 dir2.zip 14/05/2021 dir3.zip

Now I want to delete files older than 12 days , which means dir1 should be deleted.

How can I achieve this through linux scripting or any recommended command ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking.  Are you asking about the timestamp of the zipfile or the timestamp of the original directories you zipped? And do you mean to delete old zips, or old directories?

Comment: If I zipped the old file today, it will be with today's date
and in this case (find command with -mtime 12 )option will not work, I want to delete zip based on the actual create date and time of the file which it zipped later

Comment: Then edit your question to that effect.

Comment: You could build a small script that sets the name of your zip file with the date in it.  Or use  `touch -r` to change the zip file's time and date stamps to the ones on the directory.